# Exception while using render_to_string_with_wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I have a problem with header and footer options when i try a render_to_string_with_wicked_pdf.

```
  def generate_voucher
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    unless @order.blank?
      pdf = render_to_string_with_wicked_pdf({:pdf => 'generate_voucher.html.erb',
                              :layout => 'voucher.html',
                              :save_only                      => true,
                              :header => { :html => { :template => 'shared/voucher_header.pdf.erb'}}
                            })
#                           :layout       => 'voucher.html',
#                           :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?,
#                           :orientation  => 'Landscape',
#                           :no_background => true)
      @order.save_pdf(pdf)
      redirect_to :action => "foo", :id => order.id
    end
  end
```

If I render without header or footer option works. However when I try to use these options throws this exception:

```
***************WICKED***************
Rendering template within layouts/voucher
Rendering store/generate_voucher
Rendered shared/_voucher_footer (0.0ms)
Rendering template within layouts/voucher
Rendering shared/voucher_header.pdf.erb
***************WICKED***************
Rendering template within layouts/voucher
Rendering store/generate_voucher
Rendered shared/_voucher_footer (0.0ms)
Rendering template within layouts/voucher
Rendering shared/voucher_header.pdf.erb
```

I create in shared a partial view called header.pdf.erb and footer.pdf.erb.

Which could be the problem?

Also when i try to use this plugin on unix system the pdf generated throw a error format message.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

When I had the same problem I discovered that I had the wkhtmltopdf version `0.9.9`. By upgrading it to `0.11.0 rc1` the problem was fixed.

Comment: can you explain how you got the 0.9.9 and 0.11.0 regarding to the [available versions](http://rubygems.org/gems/wicked_pdf)